# Is there a way to make VSCode show errors for unresolved types in .d.ts files?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I love working with TypeScript in VSCode and seeing all the errors automatically pop up with red underlining. I even set `"typescript.tsserver.experimental.enableProjectDiagnostics": true` so that I can see any errors pop up on any file and have the file turn red in my tree.

But one thing that feel is sorely missing is the ability to automatically flag (as an error) any **unresolved types in the global `.d.ts` type files**.

Currently, if I write something in a `.ts` file like this:

```js
// example.ts

const a: Age | NotADefinedType = "foo";
//             ^ This errors bc it's unresolved
```

Then I get an error and a red squiggly line showing that this is an unresolved type. This is great.

But if I use an unresolved type in a `.d.ts` file I don't get any error. For example:

```js
// types.d.ts

type Age = number;
type Quality = Age | NotADefinedType;
//                   ^ I want this to error, but it doesn't
```

All this does is turn `Quality` into type `any`, which can be quite dangerous for the rest of my code. I don't get any warning that the `NotADefinedType` is unresolved, except for when I [move my mouse over NotADefinedType](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-5/#display-unresolved-types) and I see `type NotADefinedType = /* unresolved */ any` in the quick info popup.

Is there a way to turn these kinds of warnings on in `.d.ts` files to avoid these errors of accidentally turning types into `any` ?

Comment: This might be a result of how union types are handled. In the second case you have one valid part. What happens if both are undefined? Also, I recommend to disallow the `any` type, which will then error when you try to work with type `Quality`, I suppose.

Comment: This is not just a result of how union types or handled, because the unreferenced type in the union type errors in a `.ts` file, but not in a `.d.ts` file. (Example above updated). By the way, how can I *disallow* the `any` type?

Comment: Disable implicit any in your [tsconfig file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) and disable explicit any in [ESLint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-explicit-any.md). Gives you some work to do, but after that you really make use of the "type" part of Typescript. Btw. the effect that no error is raised in d.ts is what I mean. It looks like this is something to be mentioned in the TS Github repo.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. For me it was the `skipLibCheck` option. Maybe this is the same for you? Check out [my answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71977603/1037273) for more details

Comment: Removing `"skipLibCheck"` resolved the issue for me.

Comment: **Update:** If you're using **Next.js** you need to explicitly set it to `false` instead of removing it. Otherwise NextJS will just add it back with `true` value when you run something like `npm run dev` or perhaps `npm build`.