# No Typescript error for unresolved types in .d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, typescript

[image]

For as long as I can remember, Typescript didn't warn about unresolved/undefined types in `.d.ts` files. I could run `tsc` and it wouldn't have any errors. I already have `noImplicitAny` enabled. This file is also in my tsconfig's `include`. Is this expected or is there an issue with my setup? Is there a way to make this an error?

Here's a related question specifically about VS Code ([Is there a way to make VSCode show errors for unresolved types in .d.ts files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905791/is-there-a-way-to-make-vscode-show-errors-for-unresolved-types-in-d-ts-files)), I'm experiencing the same issue in VS Code, but even `tsc` has the issue.

Answer (score 16):

I was looking for an answer to the same question. In my case, it turned out that I was using a framework (SvelteKit) that had `skipLibCheck: true` in the default `tsconfig.json`. So it wasn't just the imports: there was no type checking at all in my `.d.ts` files. Maybe this is the same for you?

Note that setting `skipLibCheck: false` (the default if it's not set) can have some other consequences relating to performance and possible conflicts between `.d.ts` files in your `node_modules`. See [the documentation on skipLibCheck](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#skipLibCheck).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, your hint worked with me.
Note: I was just using "Vite.js" (SvilteKit is also using Vite.js), so the source of the default "skipLibCheck: true" is Vite.js